# python list creation including generator and non_generator

Tags: python, list, generator, creation

Seems like there should be an easier way to do this:

```
header_line = [x for x in my_dict.keys()]
header_line.insert(0, "1st column\t2nd column")
header_line.append("note")
print "\t".join(map(str, header_line))
```

naively i thought the following should work, but get syntax error on the header_line:

```
header_line = ["1st column", "2nd column", x for x in my_dict.keys(), "note"] 
print "\t".join(map(str, header_line))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
header_line = ['1st column', '2nd column'] + [x for x in my_dict.keys()] + ['note']
```

As mentioned in the comments, for this case you can just use `my_dict.keys()` or `list(my_dict)`, but the above example is still useful as an example of how to do this when the list comprehension can't be trivially eliminated.

Comment: You can use `list(my_dict)`.

Comment: Yeah, that's true for this example, although it's still useful to know this way of doing it if you have a "real" list comprehension that can't be eliminated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) if you have a more generaty generator:

```
import itertools

print "\t".join(itertools.chain(["1st column", "2nd column"], my_dict, ["note"]))
```